# How can I import a module and run it without having the rest of the program run?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, operating-system, sys

When I try to import a module to run it with specific inputs, the beginning part of the python script i'm calling gets run too which asks me for user input. I am not allowed to change the contents of that file in any way. How can I suppress that beginning part from running and just test the function I want to test in isolation?

```
module_path = os.path.join(root_dir, _dir, filename)  
mod = imp.load_source(modified_file, module_path)

point_counter = 0
if(mod.Function(2, 5) != True):
   point_counter+=1
if(mod.Function(2, 4) != False):
   point_counter+=1
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do there but might 
`from module import function` be what you're looking for ?

Comment: @Trolldejo That is basically what I am doing with os, but the problem is that since the parts of the program that I am trying to run are not in a main function, when I try to call a specific function in the program, ie. mod.Function(2, 5), the parts not in the function are also called which ask me for user input.

Comment: concidering the use of imp.load_source, I guess you do are using python2. May you confirm ? If so please remove the python3 tag

Comment: @Trolldejo No I use python3.

Comment: ok, my bad ;) 
may you give me the content of your variables so I can test it on  my terminalt to make sure my solution works for you ?

Comment: root_dir = /.root/
     _dir = /path_to_directory_I_want_to_get_program_from/
     filename = _file.py
     modified_file = file

Comment: you can't import part of a module without running through it. The "filename" isn't written the good way. What you may do is copy past it so you can edit the code maybe..?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046615/how-to-import-function-from-a-module-given-absolute-path/44049215#44049215