# How to import function from a module given absolute path?

Tags: python-3.x, import, module, path

```
from bar import foo
```

allows one to import function foo from module bar, **without importing the whole module.**

Now, this thread: [Python 3.4: How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381264/python-3-4-how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path]) shows different methods to import a module given it's full path depending on python's version.

Is their a way to import function foo from module bar given the absolute path of bar and without importing whole module bar ?

Thanks in advance for any tips

Comment: I don't think there's `import x from y` syntax in Python, what you're probably looking for is `from x import y`. And no, it doesn't allow the said behavior, it still runs through the whole module. The only difference is that you don't get the module namespace.

Comment: thanks for your comment, I did edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such way.

That said...

```
from bar import foo
```

Is also importing the whole module **bar**

it is like:

```
import bar
foo = bar.foo
del globals['bar']
```